# Help arranging text with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.6]
\draw[thick,<->] (0,14) node[above]--(0,0)--(14,0) node[right];
\draw[thick,-] (0,-1) node[above]--(0,0)--(-1,0) node[right];

\draw[very thick, green, domain=0:14] plot (\x,7);
\draw (2.3,-0.5) node[label=below: x] {};
\draw (7,-0.5) node[label=below: y] {};
\draw (11.7,-0.5) node[label=below: u] {};
\draw[color=green] (7,8.5) node[label=below: Constant] {};
\draw (3,-2.7) node[label=below: Low] {};
\draw (10,-2.7) node[label=below: High] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and two questions:

1. I want to add rotated text to the y-axis. I've tried `\draw[rotate=90]…` But it doesn't work.
2. How can I duplicate the plot, so to speak, and display both plots side by side?

Comment: First of all, it is recommended to ask only *one* question per question. I would suggest to start with the most important one and if needed ask the second one later. Additionally, can you please show, what you've *exactly* tried? Best (and recommended) would be to extend your code snippet to a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{documet}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7]
        % grid and axis
        \draw[gray!15] (-6,-6) grid (6,6);
        \draw[line width=.5pt,-latex] (-6,0)--(6,0) node[right] () {\small $x$};
        \draw[line width=.5pt,-latex] (0,-6)--(0,6) node[above] () {\small $y$};
        \foreach \i in {-6,-5,...,-1,1,2,...,5}{
            \draw[thick] (\i,0)--(\i,-.05) node[below] () {\footnotesize \bfseries \i} ;
            \draw[thick] (0,\i)--(-.05,\i) node[left]  () {\footnotesize \bfseries \i} ;
            \node[below left] at (0,0) {\footnotesize \bfseries 0};
        }   
        \draw[cyan] (0,3) node[rotate=90,fill=white] () {\bfseries Text on y axis};
        \draw(3,4) node[fill=red,draw=blue] () {\bfseries Text on the plane};
        \draw[blue,line width=2pt] plot[domain=-5:5,smooth] (\x,{2*sin(\x r)});
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[xshift=8,scale=.7]
        % grid and axis
        \draw[gray!15] (-6,-6) grid (6,6);
        \draw[line width=.5pt,-latex] (-6,0)--(6,0) node[right] () {\small $x$};
        \draw[line width=.5pt,-latex] (0,-6)--(0,6) node[above] () {\small $y$};
        \foreach \i in {-6,-5,...,-1,1,2,...,5}{
            \draw[thick] (\i,0)--(\i,-.05) node[below] () {\footnotesize \bfseries \i} ;
            \draw[thick] (0,\i)--(-.05,\i) node[left]  () {\footnotesize \bfseries \i} ;
            \node[below left] at (0,0) {\footnotesize \bfseries 0};
        }   
        \draw[cyan] (0,3) node[rotate=90,fill=white] () {\bfseries Text on y axis};
        \draw(3,4) node[fill=red,draw=blue] () {\bfseries Text on the plane};
        \draw[green,line width=2pt] plot[domain=-5:5,smooth] (\x,{2*cos(\x r)});
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```